# Writing via TextIO.write with Sessions windowing raises GroupByKey consumption exception

Tags: apache-beam

When using session windowing and writing to a file via TextIO.write in Apache Beam 2.0.0, the following exception is generated by calling TextIO.write():

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: GroupByKey must have a valid Window merge function.  Invalid because: WindowFn has already been consumed by previous GroupByKey`

The exception occurs even when there are no intervening `GroupByKey`s to potentially consume the window.  I've included code -- the main function illustrates the problem, and includes a helper policy writer class for 2.0.0.

```
import org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileBasedSink;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.TextIO;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.fs.ResolveOptions;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.fs.ResourceId;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.*;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.windowing.*;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.values.TimestampedValue;
import org.joda.time.Duration;
import org.joda.time.Instant;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import org.joda.time.format.ISODateTimeFormat;


public class TestSessionWindowToFile {
    /**
     * Support class: a filename policy for getting one file per window.
     * See https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/release-2.0.0/examples/java/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/examples/common/WriteOneFilePerWindow.java
     */
    public static class LocalPerWindowFiles extends FileBasedSink.FilenamePolicy {
        private static final DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER = ISODateTimeFormat.hourMinute();
        private final String prefix;

        public LocalPerWindowFiles(String prefix) {
            this.prefix = prefix;
        }

        public String filenamePrefixForWindow(IntervalWindow window) {
            return String.format("%s-%s-%s",
                    prefix, FORMATTER.print(window.start()), FORMATTER.print(window.end()));
        }

        @Override
        public ResourceId windowedFilename(
                ResourceId outputDirectory, WindowedContext context, String extension) {
            IntervalWindow window = (IntervalWindow) context.getWindow();
            String filename = String.format(
                    "%s-%s-of-%s%s",
                    filenamePrefixForWindow(window), context.getShardNumber(), context.getNumShards(),
                    extension);
            return outputDirectory.resolve(filename, ResolveOptions.StandardResolveOptions.RESOLVE_FILE);
        }

        @Override
        public ResourceId unwindowedFilename(
                ResourceId outputDirectory, Context context, String extension) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unsupported.");
        }
    }


    /**
     * Creating a session windows and then asking TextIO to write the results leads to
     * "java.lang.IllegalStateException: GroupByKey must have a valid Window merge function.
     * Invalid because: WindowFn has already been consumed by previous GroupByKey"
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pipeline p = Pipeline.create();

        PCollection<String> input = p.apply(
                Create.timestamped(
                        TimestampedValue.of("this", new Instant(1)),
                        TimestampedValue.of("is", new Instant(2)),
                        TimestampedValue.of("a", new Instant(3)),
                        TimestampedValue.of("test", new Instant(4)),
                        TimestampedValue.of("test", new Instant(5)),
                        TimestampedValue.of("test", new Instant(50)),
                        TimestampedValue.of("test", new Instant(51)),
                        TimestampedValue.of("test", new Instant(52))
                )
        );

        PCollection<String> windowedInputs = input
                // session windowing fails:
                .apply(Window.into(Sessions.withGapDuration(new org.joda.time.Duration(10))));
                // sliding windowing succeeds:
                //.apply(Window.into(SlidingWindows.of(new Duration(30)).every(new Duration(10))));

        // Invoke counting of elements so that sessioning is more clear
        PCollection<KV<String, Long>> counts =
                windowedInputs.apply(Count.perElement());
        PCollection<String> writeableStrings = counts.apply("Convert to text",
            ParDo.of(new DoFn<KV<String, Long>, String>() {
            @ProcessElement
            public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
                String word = c.element().getKey();
                Long count = c.element().getValue();
                c.output(String.format("%s,%d", word, count));
            }
        }));

        writeableStrings
                .apply(TextIO.write()
                        .to("i_am_ignored_given_filename_policy")
                        .withFilenamePolicy(new LocalPerWindowFiles("results/testSessionWindow"))
                        .withWindowedWrites()
                        .withNumShards(1)
        );
        p.run();
    }
}
```

I've seen no effect from clarifying intentions around watermarks/triggering, timestamp combining, Window.remerge()ing,
or using Beam 2.1.0 (and Beam 2.1.0 includes a default filename policy that knows how to write windowed files as well as unwindowed files).

Logging demonstrates that the sessions are correctly constructed, and a SlidingWindow works successfully produces output files (using variants like `.apply( Window.into(SlidingWindows.of(new Duration(30)).every(new Duration(10))));` in lieu of `Sessions`).  This suggests a misconfigured or misbehaving interaction of the Sessions windowing + TextIO.write.

How can this code be revised to write a text file for each key+start+end window grouping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in the WriteFiles transform. I've filed https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-3122 . Unfortunately I can't think of a workaround, short of fixing the bug.

Comment: I appreciate the confirmation that it isn't worth fighting with this further -- thank you.  I wasn't able to find any clear bugs when I looked (though I am a babe in the woods starting out with this codebase), so whoever takes that on gets all my best wishes.

Comment: To help handle this issue, could you clarify what you're trying to achieve? Windows are always per-key, just some windowing strategies do the same thing independently for all keys (eg sliding and fixed windows), but for session windows the key matters, e.g. one can think of per user id sessions. Are you trying to do session windowing by treating the entire dataset as belonging to a single "key" within sessions are computed? Or do you have some sort of grouping key?

Comment: I'll edit the example so it actually involves grouping on the word and calculating counts of the times it appears -- I was too aggressive in paring down the example. I'm actually trying to group on a key and get counts.  For instance, we might receive at t=1, t=2, and t=10 data with key "earlySession", and at t=5, t=9, and t=60 data with key "lateSession".  I'm expecting sessioning with a gap of 25 t-units to result in 3 files: t_10_earlySession (info from all 3), t_9_lateSession (info from first 2), and t_60_lateSession (info from last 1). (Sorry I missed this. I'll receive emails now.)